# Transferring code from ActivityBased UI to fragment based UI

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am getting a null pointer exception at line 39 due to the text view being created in fragment.xml and its code being added in main activity class. What shall I do to the highlighted piece of code to make it work in the same way, but in the PlaceHolderFragment class?

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         /* setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        } */

        getSupportActionBar().show();



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        ***TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);***

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Any code that references elements of the fragment should be done inside the fragment.  The activity shouldn't know anything about the internals of the fragment UI.

Comment: @GabeSechan I am aware of this fact. However I am new to android and unable to figure out the analogy for this piece of code(textView part is highlighted) that is to be handled by the fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

The inflation of the textview should be inside the fragment class if it was added in the fragment layout(same as activity). So move the textview inside the **onCreateView()** method of the fragment. It should look something like this:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container,
            false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);//make this a class variable
    textView.setTextSize(40);//put this method in onStart()
    textView.setText(message);//put this method in onStart()
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Not really clear what you want me to do. Firstly, TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1); gives an error. I tried to replace view by getView() and it worked.  The next problem is that it cannot access the variable message as its refrence has been drawn in the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think you should write

```
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
```

below

```
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_message);
```